# bubble sorting logic in ruby method

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following question:

Write a function `bubble_sort(arr)` which will sort an array of
integers using the "bubble sort"

And this is the answer to it:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  sorted = false
  until sorted
    sorted = true
    (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
      if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]
        arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
        sorted = false
      end
    end
  end

  arr
end
```

1) I am having trouble understanding these lines:

```
sorted = false
      until sorted
        sorted = true
sorted = false
```

What is going on here?

2) When I tried to arrive at the solution I tried using while i < arr.length rahter than (arr.count - 1).times do |i| is there a reason to use the latter?

3) Also when I tried to come up with my own solution before looking at the answer I kept getting an error on the `if (arr[i] < arr[i+1])` part of the code that read comparison of `Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)` why might this be?

This was my code:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
x = []
i = 0
    while i < arr.length
        k = arr[i]
        if (arr[i] < arr[i+1])
            x.push(k)
        end
        i += 1
    end
x
end

y = [1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8]
puts bubble_sort(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All the business with setting `sorted` to true and false is because a single loop over the array won't be enough to sort it. The variable is set to false whenever at least one change needs to be made, so the function won't exit until it's done.
2. Using `while i < arr.length` is fine--using `times` is just a little terser since it handles incrementing i for you.
3. However, you need to do `while i < arr.length - 1` to avoid that error. The reason is that at the end of the loop, you'll access `arr[i+1]`, which will return `nil` if you're at the end of the array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Until sorted will loop until sorted is evaluated to true. Ruby conditionals treat nil and false as false values and any other object or value as true. So the loop will run until the sorted variable is true, which will happen when arr[i] is not greater than arr[i + 1].
2. Both can work. Which do you think is more expressive / easier to read?
3. You're code is looping until i = length - 1, but you have an if that reads arr[i + 1]. i + 1 will equal the length of the array, which because arrays in ruby are 0 indexed will not contain anything and return nil. The error is happening when you try to compare a fixnum with nil. Try this in a console to experiment: 
   1 - nil
   You should get the same error.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i can help you with this (one code line):

```
(n.size-1)*(n.size-1).times{(n.size-1).times{|i| n[i],n[i+1]=n[i+1],n[i] if 1==(n[i]<=>n[i+1])}}
```

And the values for "n" maybe be a string or array or something like (duck)

Note: I suggest for using a ***sort*** method embbebed from standard library of ruby

Answer (score 0):

Best Case Time Complexity: O(n). Best case occurs when array is already sorted.

Worst and Average Case Time Complexity: O(n*n). Worst case occurs when array is reverse sorted.

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  size = arr.size
  0.upto(size-1) do |i|
    swapped = false

    (0).upto(size-i-2) do |j|
      if arr[j] > arr[j+1]
        #Swap the elements
        arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
        swapped = true
      end
    end

    break unless swapped
  end
  arr
end
```

Run it:

```
a = [64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 1]
p bubble_sort(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64]
```